Using GitHub's tag in Azure DevOps' build pipeline
The following code snippet is from our Azure DevOps' build pipeline triggered when a GitHub tag is created:
variables:
  Year: 1
  Month: 0
  BuildConfiguration: Release

name: $(Year).$(Month).$(rev:r)
pr: none
trigger:
  batch: true
  tags:
   include:
     - refs/tags/*
  paths:
    exclude:
      - README.md

As you see, the build name's is constructed by combining the values of "Year", "Month" and an automated revision number. This is not a desired approach and we'd like to use the created GitHub's tag's value to name the build. How can we achieve this goal?

You may use the logging command build.updatebuildnumber: UpdateBuildNumber: Override the automatically generated build number.
Example for PowerShell:
$gittag = git describe --tags --abbrev=0
Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$gittag"

